Display Siri Shortcuts programs in a picker - Swift (macOS)
I'm developing a Swift application for macOS.
I would like it to be able to interact with the user's shortcuts (block programs in the Shortcuts application, fig. 1). But I can't locate them...
Do you know where they are located and how I could display them in a picker (fig. 2) so that they can be selected by the user in the app?
Thanks in advance!

Fig. 1



Fig. 2



What are you going to do with the shortcut after the user picks one from your picker?

The app will launch it with an AppleScript.

Okay, then you just need its name then? The command shortcuts list will give you all the names. If you want the icons/colors as well, that would be more difficult.

Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to display the icons and colors, even if it's difficult?

There is a file ~/Library/Shortcuts/Shortcuts.sqlite that stores all the information about the shortcuts. You need to read that with a SQLite client. There is a table called ZSHORTCUTICON. The ZBACKGROUNDCOLORVALUE column stores the color as a Int32. The ZGLYPHNUMBER column presumably stores the glyph index of the icon. Presumably this is a glyph index into the SF Symbols font.

You can get the shortcuts' names using the shortcuts list command. You can run this in Swift using a Process. Here is a simple example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shortcuts = [ShortcutInfo]()
    @State var selection = ""
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Pick a shortcut", selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(shortcuts) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
        }
        .task {
            let shortcuts = (try? await loadShortcutNames()) ?? []
            self.shortcuts = shortcuts
            selection = shortcuts.first?.id ?? ""
        }

        // use "shortcuts run" to run the shortcut
        // there additional options to specify input
        // see "shortcuts help run" for more info
        Button("Run") {
            let process = Process()
            process.executableURL = URL(filePath: "/usr/bin/shortcuts")
            process.arguments = ["run", selection]
            try? process.run()
        }
    }
}

struct ShortcutInfo: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

func loadShortcutNames() async throws -> [ShortcutInfo] {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(filePath: "/usr/bin/shortcuts")

    // also get the UUID of the shortcut so that ShortcutInfo can be Identifiable
    process.arguments = ["list", "--show-identifiers"]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        try process.run()
        return try await pipe.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines.compactMap { line in

            // parse the shortcut name and ID
            guard let (_, name, id) = line.wholeMatch(of: /(.*) \(([A-Z0-9-]*)\)/)?.output else {
                return nil
            }
            return ShortcutInfo(id: String(id), name: String(name))
        }.reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }
    } onCancel: {
        process.terminate()
    }
}

For the icon and background color of the shortcuts though, they are stored in ~/Library/Shortcuts/Shortcuts.sqlite. You would need a SQLite client to read the database, and reverse-engineer the data. This would be quite fragile, as the database schema could very well change in future versions of macOS, so I wouldn't recommend that.
Hopefully there will be a proper API for accessing Shortcuts in the future.
